# C pointers and calling methods?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm new to C and I'm having a hard time understanding how to call methods with pointers. Currently this code should reverse a null-terminated string, but I get the errors

```
main.c:8:12: error: use of undeclared identifier 'sas'
         char* N = sas;
                   ^ main.c:10:10: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'char' to parameter of type
       'char *'; remove * [-Wint-conversion]
         reverse(*N);
                 ^~ ./header.h:3:27: note: passing argument to parameter 'N' here EXTERN void reverse(char *N);
```

My actual code is this: 
Main:

```c
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char* N = sas; 
    reverse(*N); 
}
```

reverse:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h
#include <stdlib.h>

void reverse(char *str) 
{
    char* end = str; 
    char temp; 
    printf("this is *str: %c\n", *str); 
    if (str) 
    { 
        while (*end) 
        {
            ++end: 
        } 
        end--; 
        while (str < end) 
        { 
            temp = *str
            *str++ = *end; 
            *end-- = temp; 
        }
    }
 }
```

header.h:

```c
#define EXTERN extern
EXTERN void reverse(char *N)
```

thanks for the help and time!

Comment: 1. Please choose a better coding style, this style is very difficult to follow, 2. What is `sas`? what are you trying to do? 3. Your code has several reasons not to compile, for example you have `++end:`??? and a lot of  closing `}` braces that apparently are not needed, though I suspect you might have left code out.

Comment: You probably need `char *N = "sas";` (a string), and you should call `reverse(N)`.  Then you'll just crash because strings aren't modifiable.  So, in reality, you need `char N[] = "sas";`.  Of course, it will be hard to spot the difference between the original and the reversed string.  You probably should test with `char N[] = "xyz";` or something else asymmetric.  You're printing in `reverse()` is going to print a single character, not the entire string.  You should print the 'after' string in `main()`, too.  Otherwise, you won't know whether your code made the correct change.

Comment: `reverse()` has no block. Please post complete code, stripped down to the relevant parts.

Comment: sorry, I'm working off an interview book and this is the code they have -- besides the main method -- so the reverse method is the whole method. I'm just confused on how to actually call the thing. I apologize for the poorly written code, but I'm am a foreigner to C.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there're many syntax errors within that piece of code:

1. 'sas' what is that? your compiler thinks it's a variable but can't find any with that name. if you wanted to put a "sas" string, then:

   ```
   char* N = "sas";
   ```
2. inconsistant brackets. More closing brackets than opening ones, and no opening bracket after declaring your function.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
    char* N = "sas"; 
    reverse(*N); 
}
```

First you make `N` point to a string constant. Then you try to reverse what `N` points to. But since `N` points to a string constant, you're trying to reverse a string constant. By definition, constants cannot have their values changed.

Answer (score -3):

As I understand it, you are trying to reverse a string. This is just a slight modification of your code.

Full Source:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

void reverse(char *N);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{ 
  char strSas[] = "sas";
  reverse(strSas);
}

void reverse(char *str)
{
  char* end = str; 
  char temp; 
  if(str) {       
    printf("this is *str: %c\n", *str); 
    while(*end) {
      ++end;
    } 
    end--; 
    while(str < end) { 
      temp = *str;
      *str = *end; 
      *end = temp;

      ++str;
      --end;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `reverse(*N)` won't compile since `reverse()` expects a `char *`.

Comment: Note that trying to reverse a string literal (constant string) is likely to crash.

Comment: `reverse("sas")` is UB. String literals are read-only. Also, `reverse()` computes a pointer that may be outside of the array range of `str`: with the empty string, `end` will point to one position before `str`, which is against the standard.

Comment: I am not trying to fix every possible edge case for Chris.